# Who were parents of Xavier Rebholz who was born 1826 in Prussia?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, prussia

I'm looking for my gg grandfather's ancestors.

His name was Xavier Rebholz:

1. Born in 1826 in Prussia,
2. Died 09 JULY 1891 in Minneapolis.
3. Married Mary Gerger, who was born in 1835 in Bavaria, died 01 OCT 1919 in Minneapolis.
4. He was listed as a stone mason in the 1870 Federal Census of Minneapolis.

He is my brick wall.

Does anyone have an idea for how I could find his parents?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  I hope you do not mind that I have taken the liberty of applying some formatting to your question and focussing it down to finding your 2nd great grandfather's parents first.  We'll need to find them before we can establish their parents and so on.

Comment: How strong is your evidence that he was from Prussia? It's sometimes helpful to look at surname distribution. Of course, it's a very rough and ready, unscientific approach but it can help prioritise, especially given that German records tend to be decentralised. The site http://worldnames.publicprofiler.org shows Rebholz being particularly strong today in BADEN-WÜRTTEMBERG and RHEINLAND-PFALZ, especially the towns of DORNHAN, KONSTANZ, 
SIGMARINGENDORF, LANDAU and STUTTGART. There are few in what was Prussia except in Berlin.

Comment: Apart from the 1870 Census, you don't list what sources you have for the information you posted.  It's a pretty big leap backwards to go from there to a birth.  Was your great-grandfather naturalized?  Does he have siblings?  What church (if any) did he attend?  What about other people in his social circle? Work in small steps rather than trying to make huge leaps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the birthdate of 1826 for Xavier Rebholz came from the record below which confirms that he was a Mason.

> "Minnesota, Death Records, 1866-1916," index, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/XP6M-X21 : accessed 05 Dec
>   2014), Xavier Rebholz, 09 Jul 1891; citing Minneapolis, Hennepin,
>   Minnesota, Public Health Center, St. Paul; FHL microfilm 1499013.

The closest match, and only likely candidate, that I could find at FamilySearch.org is the record below for a Franz Xaver Rebholz born to Elisabetha Mayer and Andreas Rebholz on 7 Dec 1823 and baptized on 8 Dec 1823 at Katholisch, Gunningen, Schwarzwaldkreis, Wuerttemberg:

> "Deutschland, Geburten und Taufen 1558-1898," index, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/N5ZW-NXP : accessed 05 Dec
>   2014), Franz Xaver Rebholz, 08 Dec 1823; citing ; FHL microfilm
>   1052287.

If Xavier Rebholz had siblings named Elisabetha and/or Andreas, or used either name for any of his children then I think that would be cause to look hard at this record.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and pardon my delay in responding. I don't know of any siblings for Xavier. An 1885 Minneapolis Census has him with wife Mary and sons Joseph, Frank(also a mason), George, John and Julius.